# Testing a wide variety of computers with a small company

Tags: windows, testing

I work for a small dotcom which will soon be launching a reasonably-complicated Windows program. We have uncovered a number of "WTF?" type scenarios that have turned up as the program has been passed around to the various not-technical-types that we've been unable to replicate.

One of the biggest problems we're facing is that of testing: there are a total of three programmers -- only one working on this particular project, me -- no testers, and a handful of assorted other staff (sales, etc). We are also geographically isolated. The "testing lab" consists of a handful of VMWare and VPC images running sort-of fresh installs of Windows XP and Vista, which runs on my personal computer. The non-technical types try to be helpful when problems arise, we have trained them on how to most effectively report problems, and the software itself sports a wide array of diagnostic features, but since they aren't computer nerds like us their reporting is only so useful, and arranging remote control sessions to dig into the guts of their computers is time-consuming.

I am looking for resources that allow us to amplify our testing abilities without having to put together an actual lab and hire beta testers. My boss mentioned rental VPS services and asked me to look in to them, however they are still largely very much self-service and I was wondering if there were any better ways. How have you, or any other companies in a similar situation handled this sort of thing?

**EDIT:** According to the lingo, our goal here is to expand our systems testing capacity via an elastic computing platform such as Amazon EC2. At this point I am not sure suggestions of beefing up our unit/integration testing are going to help very much as we are consistently hitting walls at the systems testing phase. Has anyone attempted to do this kind of software testing on a cloud-type service like EC2?

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I believe logging application activity and error/exception details is the most useful strategy to communicate technical details about problems on the customer side. You can add a feature to automatically mail you logs or let the customer do it manually.

The question is, what exactly do you mean to test? Are you only interested in error-free operation or are you also concerned how the software is accepted at the customer side (usability)?

For technical errors, write a log and manually test in different scenarios in different OS installations. If you could add unit tests, it could also help. But I suppose the issue is that it works on your machine but doesn't work somewhere else.

You could also debug remotely by using IDE features like "Attach to remote process" etc. I'm not sure how to do it if you're not in the same office, likely you need to build a VPN.

If it's about usability, organize workshops. New people will be working with your application, and you will be video and audio recording them. Then analyze the problems they encountered in a team "after-flight" sessions. Talk to users, ask what they didn't like and act on it.

Theoretically, you could also built this activity logging into the application. You'll need to have a clear idea though what to log and how to interpret the data.

Comment: Sadly the 'WTF' issues tend to be things that are outside the scope of what the logger is capable of recording. The error reporting process is very well defined and the users are trained on it, but there are a variety of environmental issues with Windows and will often occur before the logger even starts, or makes its connection to the logger service. Architecturally this software is spread out in pieces due to business requirements. Many of our woes are related to the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would be asking is if you have any automated testing being done?

By this I mean mainly mean unit and integration testing. If not then I think you need to immediately look into unit testing, firstly as part of your build processes, and second via automated runs on servers. Even with a UI based application, it should be possible to find software that can automate the actions of a user and tell you when a test has failed.

Apart from the tests you as developers can think of, every time a user finds a bug, you should be able to create a test for that bug, reproduce it with the test, fix it, and then add the test to the automated tests. This way if that bug is ever re-introduced your automated tests will find it before the users do. Plus you have the confidence that your application has been tested for every known issue before the user sees it and without someone having to sit there for days or weeks manually trying to do it.